# nHibernate Envers MOD

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I am new to nHibernate Envers, I am Tracking entity changes at property level, which creates columns with the properties names with a suffix of _MOD by default, there is a option of changing this suffix.

http://envers.bitbucket.org/#envers-envers-tracking-properties-changes-queries

But, i need the columns names for these MOD flags based on ColumnName_MOD instead of PropertyName_MOD.

Where can I change this configuration.
Any clues would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Su

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't today.

The reason it works this way is for consistency - some "MOD columns" doesn't have to be "mapped" to one single database columns but to its property. Eg components, user types with multiple columns and so forth, all use one MOD column even though the audited data is (can be) represented as multiple columns.

If you want to, you can report your issue here
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can a custom mapping to the MOD columns can be done ? so i can manually create the mod column names to match with the actual column names. ?

Comment: As said, there isn't a one to one mapping between normal column names and MOD column names on audit tables.
But no, AFAIK - no, you can't set the column names for MOD columns today.
Feel free to add a JIRA ticket about this.